# Can you support multiple domains from vcenter

Tags: vmware-vcenter

I have an esxi server with guests on 1 domain and another esx server with guest on different domain. Is it possible to manage bother esx machines from the 1 instance of vcenter??

Thks

Answer (score 5):

As long as the server hosting vCenter can connect directly to both ESX machines, it doesn't matter what the status of the guests are or what domains they are connected to.